# Django re-calculate column on model anytime a new model is created or an existing is saved

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model that has an aggregate field on it. I'd like to recalculate the agg field whenever the model is updated, or calculate it initially if the model is being created.

model (Just as an example):

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
   id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   last_active_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

   agg_field = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Where the agg_field should be a method such as (This could be anything, just wrote this as an example):

```
FooBar.objects.filter('last_active_date__gt': datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).annotate(Count('pk')))
```

So essentially every time the model is updated or created, it should recalculate this column

Comment: It makes no sense to store that in an column, since that column is defined such that each record has an `agg_field`, but that would then imply that we store the same value for all records.

Comment: I just used that queryset as an example but in reality it's traversing a tree of items, and calculating based on items that are related to it in the tree. 

Currently this is done on the fly in a queryset anytime we need to access the agg_value via an annotation, but this generally speaking is extremely ill performant for queries that attempt to select hundreds or thousands of items.

Comment: Thus it won't be the same value for all records